# Google translate v 2.0 broken by a change at Google

Tags: google-api, google-translate

Last week I started receiving code 403, when attempting to use the translation API with my code:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
 }
}
```

When I tried to review my account at Google's developer site, seems that they have changed the site and although the site remembers that I pay for the translation services it has no recollection of my history and does not provide information as to what have changed.

Does anyone else that uses Google API have such experience? Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Thanks,
Asaf

Answer (score 0):

I have also had this problem with the Translate API. I was even charged for the requests that returned an error! Your best bet would be to contact google support.